# Click event is not working in HTML Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am developing a responsive website using html and css. I had to use Jquery to click my toggle menu. The click event is not working. The following is my code.

```
JQuery :

$(document).ready(function(){

    $toggleCollapse = $('.toggle-collapse');

$toggleCollapse.click(function(){
    $toggleClass('collapse');

})
});

CSS :

.collapse {
    height: 30rem;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing like `$toggleClass('collapse')` in jQuery.. Please post the correct working code.

Comment: What is `collapse`? A css class? A library function (like bootstrap)?

Comment: Updated it. CSS class.

Comment: Start by reading the [toggleClass() docs](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$(this).toggleClass('collapse');` to toggle given class.

Here is demo :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $toggleCollapse = $('.toggle-collapse');

  $toggleCollapse.click(function() {
    //use this 
    $(this).toggleClass('collapse');

  })
});
```

```css
.collapse {
  height: 30rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle-collapse">SOMETHING </button>
```